# SD card Files not Writeable

Tags: java, android

I'm currently not sure what is the issue that im having with my app. I believe that the problem is asking for write to sd card permissions

Currently I can move a file from internal memory to a file withing internal memory. The issue arises when I try to do the same within the sd card files

One issue can be that when I search for the files inside the sd card I am hardcoding the path. The reason for this is that when I call the method:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
//should return the path of the SD card but returns internal device memory
```

Since this method returns the device memory there is not another method that would return the path of the sd card. I went into android device monitor and under file manager I found the path for the sd card to be "/storage/57e5-053e".
I have put in files from my computer and verified that the files are being stored there through device monitor.

What I have tried is checking the state of the sd card and allowed my app to get write permissions from the manifest as well as programmatically which I believe to be correct.

The issue can be seen when I create a file using a path inside the sd card and I call the `canWrite()` method which always returns false.
I can however call the `canRead()` method on the file and it always returns true
I have been working on this issue for a week already and I haven't found a solution for it, so any help would be appreciated.

**TRYING TO MOVE FILE WORKS IF DONE WITHIN DEVICE MEMORY**

```
 try{
            File afile =new File("/storage/57E5-053E/Android/data");

           if( afile.canWrite())
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CAN WRITE TO FILE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


            if(afile.renameTo(new File("/storage/57E5-053E/TESTDATA/")))
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "FILE MOVED SUCCESSFULLY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "FILE FAILED TO MOVE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**MANIFEST ASKING FOR PERMISSIONS**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".createDir"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity_delete"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity android:name=".moveKnox"></activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**MAKING SURE I CAN WRITE TO EXTERNAL STORAGE**

```
public boolean isStoragePermissionGranted()
{

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=23)//works
    {

        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            Log.v(TAG, "Permission Granted");
            return true;

        } else
        {
            Log.v(TAG, "Permission NOT Granted");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
        Log.v(TAG, "Permission Granted");
    return true;
}
```

**MAKING SURE THERE IS SD CARD AVAILABLE**

```
void ExtraState()
    {
        boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
        boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            // We can read and write the media
            mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
          //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CAN WRITE",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
            // We can only read the media
            mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
            mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CAN READ ONLY",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states, but all we need
            //  to know is we can neither read nor write
            mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NOT AVAILABLE",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: GetExternalastorageDirectory() will give you the path to external memory. There is no such function to determine a removable micro SD card. But if you can find the path to it then you will not be able to write to it as Google does not allow that in modern Android versions. Your app on only write in the multiple paths delivered by getExternalFilesDirs(). So have a look. The second one will be on the card.

Comment: @greenapps Thank you for such a quick response. What I am trying to create is a file manager application. My goal is to create and modify files in the device memory and the Sd card. I tried to call the getExternalFilesDirs but it also returns the internal memory. Is there a way to get the path to the SD card programmatically. I apologize if you already mentioned it. I am just not grasping it.

Comment: The problem that im having is that I want to display at the same time that Im creating or modifying a file. Just how i can see the files when the device is connected to the computer. I want to be able to display it in my application. Is there something that you reccomend.

Comment: In your application? Which application?

Comment: I created a file manager app that displays the contents of internal memory and sd card memory. The issue that i have is that when im trying to transfer data from the sd card to internal memory I somehow dont have rights to do so. I check the File to see if i can write to it and it returns false. My whole goal is to be able to transfer data from the sd card to internal memory can you recommend me an approach so this can be done.

Comment: Both getExternalFilesDir and Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory return internal memory so I am unable to write to the SD card. The only way i can see the contents of the sd card is by hardcoding the location. But it seems as if the location that im inputting may be read only. I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Which android version on your device? getExternalFilesDir() will return one directory. getExternalFilesDirs() should return two paths. If you cannot determine the path to the micro sd card programmatically then add a file picker so the user can pick it.

Comment: sorry for not being very descriptive. Thank you for your help I see what you mean. my last question would be when calling File[] dirs = getExternalFilesDirs(null);        is there a way to return the parent path for dirs[0] or dirs[1] when i call the method get parent file it just goes back one file. I know you can do it by calling getParentFile multiple times but im pretty sure thats not the correct way

Comment: Well why dont you first tell if the second path is indeed on the micro sd card? Please tell how those paths looks like.

Comment: the function is indeed returning the correct paths.       dir[0] = /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.filemanager/files    dir[1]= /storage/57e5-053e/Android/data/com.example.filemanager/files  Both are returning acceptable paths.

Comment: You still did not answer if one path is on the micro sd card. And what do you think is the root of the micro sd card? And did you compare the paths with getExternalStorageDirectory()? Please give your comments. Come to the point.